# How to get the Intent name (from Watson API) using NODEJS

Tags: node.js, watson-assistant

I am using IBM watson assistant for NLU and backend I am using Nodejs for API calling. I am able to connect and get JSON response from watson assistant. For that I am using the code bellow.

When my App send the message text to API and get a return **I need to Know what was the Intent name that answered the question.**

I have alredy implemeted a print of the returned JSON (see below), but I can not identify the Intent name on it.

I would apreciate any help in this matther.

```js
const AssistantV2 = require('ibm-watson/assistant/v2');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

// Configurar o wrapper de serviço do Assistente.
const service = new AssistantV2({
  version: '2019-02-28',
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
    apikey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // replace with API key
  })
});

const assistantId = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'; // replace with assistant ID let sessionId;

// Create session.
service
  .createSession({
    assistantId,
  })
  .then (res =>{
    sessionId = res.result.session_id;
    zz = res.headers;
    zz1 = res.statusText;
    sendMessage({
      messageType: 'text',
      text: 'estou com muita dor', // start conversation with empty message
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  }); // something went wrong });

// Send message to assistant.
function sendMessage(messageInput) {
  service
    .message({
      assistantId,
      sessionId,
      input: {messageInput, options:{'return_context': true}}
    })
    .then (res =>{
      processResponse(res.result);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    }); // something went wrong }); }
}
// Processe a resposta.
function processResponse(response) {
  // Display the output from assistant, if any. Supports only a single // text response.
  if (response.output.generic) {
    if (response.output.generic.length > 0) {
      if (response.output.generic[0].response_type === 'text') {
        console.log (response.output.generic [ 0 ] .text); }
    }
  }
}
```

*** JSON ***

```js
{
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "458",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, HEAD, OPTIONS",
    "access-control-allow-headers": "Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, X-Watson-Authorization-Token,
X-WDC-PL-OPT-OUT, X-Watson-UserInfo, X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out, X-Watson-Metadata",
    "access-control-max-age": "3600",
    "content-security-policy": "default-src 'none'",
    "x-dns-prefetch-control": "off",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;",
    "x-download-options": "noopen",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
    "x-watson-session-timeout": "session_timeout=300",
    "x-response-time": "40.583ms",
    "x-global-transaction-id": "5e03ba22807bb45fd8df7dc92eee618a",
    "x-dp-watson-tran-id": "5e03ba22807bb45fd8df7dc92eee618a",
    "x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt": "47",
    "x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency": "172",
    "date": "Thu, 18 Jun 2020 15:53:31 GMT",
    "connection": "close"
  },
  "result": {
    "output": {
      "intents": [],
      "entities": [],
      "generic": [
        {
          "response_type": "text",
          "text": "Olá.. eu sou a Dra. Home. Estou aqui para te auxiliar em informações sobre a clínica."
        },
        {
          "source": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSraIoUCWfz9tqBQRpvxZq8umDa85wBK0vtELzbrzpU94QdKyV1",
          "response_type": "image"
        }
      ]
    },
    "context": {
      "global": {
        "system": {
          "turn_count": 1
        },
        "session_id": "52dbe39f-30b0-4eb1-ba34-f48d11c28270"
      },
      "skills": {
        "main skill": {
          "system": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you try with the current API version? https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node#send-user-input-to-assistant-stateful

Comment: Hello... @data_henrik I tryed to use the example of your link, and fill it with my API Key. But I don't know what to put in the URL parameter. I puted the URL I found in the "Settings API Details" wich is "https://api.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/........../v2/assistants/....../sessions" but I received a erro "Resource not found","code":404".

Comment: The API docs have a section Service Endpoint: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node#service-endpoint Have you use that?

Comment: Hello data_henrik I used the documentations suggested by you and it work. Thank You very much.